# Including Fonts with SCSS and Create React App

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, create-react-app

I'm building a simple create-react-app and using SCSS. I downloaded a custom font and I have the .otf, .ttf, and .woff files. I was only planning on using the .otf file, but one way or another, I can't figure out where my relative reference for the file will be. Here is my directory structure:

```
app
|__public
|__src
   |__css
   |__fonts
   |__img
   |__sass
      |____abstracts
           |__(_fonts.scss)
```

In the _fonts.scss file, here is my code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LeagueGothic';
    src: local('LeagueGothic'), url(../../fonts/LeagueGothic-Regular.otf) format('otf');
}
```

I have a CSS selector in my _base.scss:

```
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'LeagueGothic', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the app being run on a dev server (note the LeagueGothic reference):
[image]

I'm not getting compilation errors or anything like that but the font isn't being applied. I'm studying webpack right now to see if I can dissect the build process and figure out where my files end up so I know where to reference. I'm sure there is an easier work-around I just can't find the direct answer.

Comment: Are you applying the font? Like: `html, body {font-family: 'LeagueGothic';}`

Comment: @AdriSolid yes I am. Sorry, I should've put that. Going to add now.

Comment: Yes i think applying font might be the solution

Comment: No I had already done that in my code. I just hadn't included it in the post. I don't think I'm referencing the file right. I'm pretty sure that's the problem I just don't know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying your format as format('opentype') as per the available types:

> The available types are: "woff", "woff2", "truetype", "opentype", "embedded-opentype", and "svg".

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/src